# redirect status code in `NextResponse.redirect()` is not working for homepage

Tags: node.js, redirect, next.js, seo

I'm using [next.js](https://nextjs.org) for my app and for SEO purposes I'm using locales inside urls.
So in response for `www.domain.com` I use [server side redirect](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/301-redirects#serverside) to redirect to a domain with locale (eg: `www.domain.com/en`.)

To fulfill the task I use next.js middleware, based on the [this example](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#prefixing-the-default-locale) presented by next.js documents:

```
import { NextMiddleware, NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/;

export const middleware: NextMiddleware = (request: NextRequest) => {
  const shouldHandleLocale =
    !PUBLIC_FILE.test(request.nextUrl.pathname) &&
    !request.nextUrl.pathname.includes("/api/") &&
    request.nextUrl.locale === "default";

  if (shouldHandleLocale) {
    const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
    url.pathname = `/en${request.nextUrl.pathname}`;
    return NextResponse.redirect(url, 308);
  }

  return undefined;
};
```

So in the function I return `NextResponse.redirect()` with a **308** status code for assigng redirect type to permanently. (read the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/301-redirects#overview-of-redirect-types) in case you want to know about redirect types)

It works fine on all pages on the app except the home page (`"/"`) in which the first request for the main domain (`www.domain.com`) responds with satus code of **307** which represents **Temporary Redirect** which is described as **"weak signal"** by google search central.

About the return type status code I still have to do some research about which one is better for SEO matters and I woukd appreciate if you can help about that.

But my main problem is that why the status code assignment is not working for home page link.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Where in your `pages` folder structure is the `_middleware` file located?

Comment: @juliomalves It's located in the `/pages` directory in which `_app` and `_document` files are located.

Comment: Do you have any [`redirects`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) configured in your `next.config.js` file?

Comment: @juliomalves Not in that file. Just Some redirections to `404` and `500` pages when the API doesn't work in `GetServerSideProps` function in pages.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this worked

```
return NextResponse.redirect(url, { status: 308 });
```

Comment: No word about it in the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response#redirect

Answer (score -1):

From what I see in the type definitions in next, the redirect signature is like follows:

```js
static redirect(url: string | NextURL | URL, init?: number | ResponseInit): NextResponse;
```

where `init` contains the `nextConfig`.

No status code is accepted in the redirect method.

Comment: `init` can also be `number`, which is used for the redirect status code.